# Passing parameters to tested app on AWS Device Farm XCUITests

Tags: xctest, aws-device-farm

I am using `XCUIApplication` `launchArguments` to pass information into my tested app, as described [in Joe Masilotti's blog](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-xcode-7/) amongst other places.  However when I run my test on AWS Device Farm, these arguments are not available from `NSProcessInfo` -- seems these arguments are not being passed through.

How can arguments be passed into a tested app on AWS Device Farm tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work for the AWS Device farm team.

Thank you for sharing the details. 
Unfortunately, we don't expose a way to provide custom cli args or environment variables. Thus the launch application with arguments would not work on device farm.

Comment: Reluctantly marking as correct, however this is disappointing; passing parameters to a tested app using `launchArguments` is a common pattern.  Are there plans to address this in future?